# How to store 4 million MongoDB documents in a Java-collection

Tags: java, mongodb, arraylist, collections

I want to store about 4 million MongoDB-documents (682 MB on the server) in some Java-collection to use it as a memory-cached Mongo-Collection. Some other documents that I query reference these documents and I need the name field to proceed. To query each referenced document to get these fields is quite expensive, so I simply tried to put them into an ArrayList with

```
someMongoCollection.find().into(new ArrayList<>())
```

which did not work at all. As soon as the memory use of the java process reached 3.35 GB, the process did not react anymore.

My next try was to get the documents in batches of 20000 and add them to an ArrayList in a while-loop. Same thing, but this time I could see that it had already added about 3 million documents to the ArrayList before it collapsed.

My last try was similar to the one before but I separated the documents in two ArrayLists, which each should hold 2 million documents and it somehow worked, but I don't think this is a proper solution, as I tried it only out of curiosity.

The documents to store are formatted like this:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("123412341234123412341234"),
    "name" : "Some Text / Some Text / Some Text / Some Text",
    "ref" : DBRef("ref", ObjectId("555566665555666655556666")),
    "cat" : "foo"
}
```

I use MongoDB 3.4 and the matching Java-Drivers.

Have you any suggestions how to do this, or ideas why it failed?

Comment: You shouldn't store a DB in memory for any reason!

Comment: did u try giving additional memory with jvm options like xms n xmx?

Comment: In this particular case a LinkedList may be of a help. While generally it requires more memory than an ArrayList, for the ArrayList you'll need an array allocation - huge chunks of continuous memory. And when the list grows, it will need twice as much memory at the same time - it allocates a new array and copies elements there, during this time both arrays are in use. LinkedList is reference based, so items may be put at different points of the heap.

Comment: I agree with @driconmax. Why have a database if you're going to read it into memory?

Comment: And to add some rough calculations: if each document is as above, it will contain about 180 chars. Each 2 byte long - 320 bytes per document. For 4 million documents - that's 1280000000 bytes or ~ 1.3 gigabytes. Multiply that by ~6 (LinkedList overhead) or by 1.2 (ArrayList overhead, but continuous memory)

Comment: so, saurabh is right - you need more RAM given to your JVM. How much - calculate based on your data amount. Keeping them inmemory is quite ok, if you need them for quick access - that's basically how all caches work.

Comment: @Dakoda I have to do this as part of an etl-process for a new database. While you are perfectly right that I could read each reference out of the database, it is quite slow if you have to do it about 4 million times.

Comment: My calculation on the LinkedList is not exactly correct - it requires ~6 times more memory per document reference than ArrayList. But the general idea is same - calculate how much memory you need, and pass that to JVM using xmx params.

Comment: Thank you for your advice @saurabh. It worked after I raised the -Xmx option to 8192m. Could you post your comment as an answer, so I can accept it?

Comment: @khusrav thank you for your calculation advice! It worked after raising the memory limit to 8192m. I tried both, ArrayList and LinkedList. Both worked, while LinkedList was 40000 ms faster than ArrayList with 306000 ms in total.

Comment: if this is some serious migration process you might also want to consider using in-memory grid with partitioning features

Comment: @khusrav Yet another reason not to use LinkedList. ArrayList does indeed use large contiguous memory. Growth factor is 1.5x so temporary max is 2.5x for both old and new arrays. But this is usually swamped by the higher per-element cost of LinkedList.